# How to decode stream of h264 bytes from udp socket to video file

Tags: java, h.264, libstreaming

I am currently developing an Android application that streams live video to a server using the libstreaming package. I am able to send the data to my laptop UDP socket, which has a type of an array of bytes. Now, I want to check if the bytes are correct and transform them into a video file. However, I do not understand how to do this. I tried to stream to an .h264 file and load it to internet resources for transforming h264 to the video. But the file had an incorrect format.

Here is the code snippet I'm using:

```java
try (FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("output.h264")) {
    DpReceive = new DatagramPacket(receive, receive.length);
    serverSocket.receive(DpReceive);
    outputStream.write(DpReceive.getData());
    outputStream.close();
}
```

Bytes looks like this

[image]

What am I doing wrong? How can I achieve my goal? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is _UDP_ required?  I believe it allows for data-packet loss.

Comment: Even if there is no data loss, Isn't that going to be a pretty small video, given that the maximum size of a datagram packet is c. 64K?

Comment: @g00se Now I am trying to show video of any size. The main goal now is to show something at all

Comment: @Reilas yes, it may be, but for live video streaming it is the best option, as I think. TCP can produce lags and freezes

Comment: You'd want to be using a dedicated Java rtsp library, not trying to roll your own with datagrams

Comment: @KirillGubanov Can you provide a short `output.h264` file (even with one video frame it is enough to test). **(1)** It's possible you need to first remove some UDP header bytes, at the receiving side, before you can use _"Internet resources for transforming h264 to the video"_ **(2)** It's possible you are not first sending the H264 bytes that have the decoder setup (called **SPS** and **PPS**)  before sending video frame bytes.

Comment: @VC.One see my 'answer'. If/when the OP copies that into the question, I shall delete it

Comment: @g00se Well it could be the beginnings of an answer from you. I cannot test Android code. I'm just passing thru to advise about H264 side of things... **Solution:** You need to convert your H264 bytes values from integers into hex Strings. This means: **(1)** Get the data into an Array then create a String variable `myHexStr` which is incrementally updated by using a For loop. **(2)** Read each byte (Array slot) as an integer number and convert that into Hex by using a `tempString = myNumberVar.toString(16);` command (or similar effect in Java).

Comment: **(3)** You need to also pad any single hex values since a byte (transformed into hex) is written as 2 characters. This means you prefix a zero in front of any single digits. You want `"0F"` not `"F"` where if the byte value is `0x0F` (or 15 decimal).. Example code like: `if( (tempString.length % 2) !== 0 ) { tempString = ("0" + tempString ); }` ... then increment it into the final hex output `myHexStr += tempString;` until the For loop ends. **(4)** Encode the final string as Base64 and try to play/save as H264... Ask anything.

Comment: *Solution: You need to convert your H264 bytes values from integers into hex Strings.* Why? datagrams are quite capable of holding binary data

Comment: @g00se The shown Base64 example did not give actual H264 binary values. If it must explicitly be Base64 data then the previous example can be used. Yes, it is more correct to send the H264 byte values directly as binary data. The Asker says _"The main goal now is to show something at all"_ so maybe a temporary solution is saving the received binary data and testing the contents to learn what else needs fixing next...

Comment: *The shown Base64 example did not give actual H264 binary values* I've just decoded it and played the video with VLC

Comment: @g00se What is your first 16 decoded characters from that shown Base64?

Comment: See my 'answer'

Comment: @g00se Okay now I see it correctly as binary. I first tested on the site: [base64decode.org](https://www.base64decode.org/) but after checking with my main "go to" tool: [conv.darkbyte.ru](https://conv.darkbyte.ru/) I see H264 NAL units properly.  As you can see yourself if you save such binary as a File it will play. Do you think it solves the Asker's problem as far as transforming the bytes into a video file?

Answer (score 1):

```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```

is a one-second sample from an 'Inside Java' episode as h264 (base64-encoded)
Saved as 'x.h264' (after decoding with base64), `file` says:

```
goose@t410:/tmp$ file x.h264
x.h264: JVT NAL sequence, H.264 video @ L 13
```

Its header (first 16 bytes):

```
goose@t410:/tmp$ xxd -l 16 x.h264 
00000000: 0000 0001 6764 000d acd9 4141 fb0e 1000  ....gd....AA....
```